# unpack dependency and repack classes using maven?

Tags: maven, jar

I am trying to unpack a maven artifact A and repack it into a new jar file in the maven project B.

Unpacking class files from artifact A into:

```
    <my.classes.folder>${project.build.directory}/staging</my.classes.folder>
```

works fine using this:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>unpack</id>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>unpack</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>com.test</groupId>
                                <artifactId>mvn-sample</artifactId>
                                <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                                <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                                <outputDirectory>${my.classes.folder}</outputDirectory>
                                <includes>**/*.class,**/*.xml</includes>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

In the same pom I now want to generate an additional jar containing the classes just unpacked:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                    <classesdirectory>${my.classes.folder}</classesdirectory>
                        <classifier>sample</classifier>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

A new jar is created but it does not contain the classes from the:

```
 ${my.classes.folder}
```

its simply a copy of the default project jar. Any ideas?

I have tried to follow this guide:

http://jkrishnaraotech.blogspot.dk/2011/06/unpack-remove-some-classes-and-repack.html

but its not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the sample you have `<classesdirectory>`, the [docs](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/jar-mojo.html) have the element as `<classesDirectory>`.  Case sensitivity matters, I think.

Comment: And that said, I think @maba's answer may be better for this use case.

Comment: Well spotted there! +1 for that.

Answer (score 8):

I would suggest you to use the [`maven-shade-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html) instead.

That will make the unpack-repack in the same invocation.

You could do something like this for example:

```xml
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <filters>
            <filter>
              <artifact>com.test:mvn-sample:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</artifact>
              <includes>
                <include>**/*.class</include>
                <include>**/*.xml</include>
              </includes>
            </filter>
          </filters>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```