# How to reference packaged resources from the jasmine maven plugin?

Tags: maven, war, jasmine, jasmine-maven-plugin

I want to use the `jasmine-maven-plugin` to test my maven `my-webapp` project. This project depends on another `my-lib` project that contains some required JavaScript libraries. When the `my-webapp` project is built, it adds the `my-lib` JAR to the `WEB-INF/lib/` path of the generated WAR. Inside the `my-lib` JAR, the needed JS resources are in folders `META-INF/resources` and `META-INF/test-resources`.

How can I reference these packaged resources from the `jasmine-maven-plugin` goals `jasmine:bdd` and `jasmine:test`?

Note that I've also tried to run the goals in the `integration-test` phase like explained [here](https://github.com/searls/jasmine-maven-plugin/issues/119), but I still can't reference the needed resources.

**UPDATE**: Would running `jetty:run-war` from within the `jasmine-maven-plugin` help? If so, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

I think you would need to first use the maven-dependency-plugin to unpack the jar, under a different goal.

Something like this: [unpack dependency and repack classes using maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13142511/unpack-dependency-and-repack-classes-using-maven)

Then you can specify the parameters, under the configuration section of the plugin for that goal, from wherever you unpacked the jar.

wherever/you/unpacked/

Run the unpack goal first, then the bdd and test.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Beznus, it looks promising.